# Where to find Windows checkdisk log?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, check-disk

I was trying to make a check disk for my Drive C but it gave me a message that the disk will be checked in the next restart and this what really happened.

Where can I find the results or log of this check in my Windows 10?

Comment: Typically the root directory if it didn't do any corrective actions it might not have generated a log

Comment: @Ramhound It's in the application event log on Windows 10 as well as 7 and 8.

Comment: Might be thinking when it's ran from a recovery environment:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your chkdsk logs in the event viewer under "Windows Logs" -> "Application" -> in the table on the right site look out for rows which have "Wininit" in the "Source" column.

Alternatively you could search for it In the event viewer using this [tutorial](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html)

By navigating to event viewer > application and searching for " chkdsk " ( without the quotes ) if the chkdsk is ran from windows if not which is your case you need to search for " wininit "

To access event viewer you need to click start and type in event viewer or launch the run box by hitting " windows key + R " and type in eventvwr.msc